# How to compare 2D vector fields and minimize the difference?

Tags: optimization, scipy, numpy, vectorization

I want to compare the field of two electrical currents and compare the resulting field to a magnetic dipol field and find magnetic momentum that minimizes the difference of the two fields.

My current approach is to calculate the field of the two currents (by superimposing the fields of the two individual currents) and then start a optimization/search algorithm that minimizes the difference of the two fields. Because I am not interested in the immediate surroundings of the dipol or wires, I mask out the area around the center (and set the values of the fields there to zero).

To compute the overall error that the search algorithm should minimize, I subtract the dipol field from the field from the two currents. I use vectorization, so I end up just substracting whole fields from each other. Feels nice, but perhaps its wrong? I assume the vecorization substracts each vector in each coordinate. I want those individual vectors to be as similar as possible and want to minimize all those individual, small errors, added up. But I fear this optimization does not take place because the fields dont look similar.

How do i compare fields effectively?

here is my code so far, so you can see all the details of how i did it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize


# def magnetic_dipol_field_in_point(dipol_coordinates, dipol_vector, point_coordinates):
#     magnetic_permeability = 4 * np.pi * 1e-7
#     direction_vector = (point_coordinates - dipol_coordinates)
#     direction_vector_norm = np.linalg.norm(direction_vector, axis=0)
#     direction_unit_vector = np.divide(direction_vector, direction_vector_norm, out=np.zeros_like(direction_vector),
#                                       where=direction_vector_norm != 0)
#     vector_product = np.dot(dipol_vector, direction_unit_vector)
#     unit_vect_prod_ = direction_unit_vector * vector_product
#     dipol_vector = dipol_vector[:, np.newaxis]
#     dipol_diff = unit_vect_prod_ - dipol_vector
#     b_vector = (magnetic_permeability / (4 * np.pi)) * (3 * dipol_diff)\
#                / np.power(direction_vector_norm, 3)
#     return b_vector

def magnetic_dipol_field_in_point(dipol_coordinates, dipol_vector, point_coordinates):
    mu_0 = 4 * np.pi * 1e-7
    direction_vector = (point_coordinates - dipol_coordinates)
    direction_vector_norm = np.linalg.norm(direction_vector, axis=0)
    direction_unit_vector = (direction_vector / direction_vector_norm)
    b_vector = (mu_0 / (4 * np.pi)) * (3 * direction_unit_vector * np.dot(dipol_vector.T, direction_unit_vector)
                                       - dipol_vector) / np.power(direction_vector_norm, 3)

    return b_vector

def magnetic_vector_in_point(current_coordinates, current, point_coordinates):
    magnetic_permeability = 4 * np.pi * 1e-7
    direction_vector = (point_coordinates - current_coordinates)
    direction_vector_norm = np.linalg.norm(direction_vector, axis=0)
    direction_unit_vector = np.divide(direction_vector, direction_vector_norm, out=np.zeros_like(direction_vector),
                                      where=direction_vector_norm != 0)
    # orthogonal_unit_vector = np.flip(direction_unit_vector, axis=0) * np.array([[-1], [1]])
    # faster version of the above:
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64795722/how-to-calculate-the-orthogonal-vector-of-a-unit-vector-with-numpy/64797015#64797015
    orthogonal_unit_vector = direction_unit_vector[::-1, :]
    np.negative(orthogonal_unit_vector[0, :], out=orthogonal_unit_vector[0, :])

    b_vector = (current * magnetic_permeability / (2 * np.pi)) * np.divide(orthogonal_unit_vector,
                                                                           direction_vector_norm,
                                                                           out=np.zeros_like(orthogonal_unit_vector),
                                                                           where=direction_vector_norm != 0)
    return b_vector


def calc_current(time, num, peak):
    return peak * np.cos(num * 2 * np.pi / 3 + time)  # time is in the interval 0..2pi


def mask_area(field, grid, coord, radius):
    x_center = coord[0]
    y_center = coord[1]
    field[0] = np.where(np.sqrt((grid[0] - x_center) ** 2 + (grid[1] - y_center) ** 2) > radius, field[0], 0)
    field[1] = np.where(np.sqrt((grid[0] - x_center) ** 2 + (grid[1] - y_center) ** 2) > radius, field[1], 0)
    return field


def main():
    size = 4
    a = 2.67e-2

    X, Y = np.mgrid[-size:size:.1, -size:size:.1]
    grid = np.vstack([X.ravel(), Y.ravel()])

    current_coordinates = np.array([[a, -a / np.sqrt(3), -a / np.sqrt(3)],
                                    [0, a, -a]])
    magnetic_fields = np.zeros([2 + 1, grid.shape[0], grid.shape[1]])

    currents = np.zeros(3)

    for i in range(0, 2):
        currents[i] = calc_current(1 + np.pi / 2, i, 1)
        currents = [5, -5, 0]
        magnetic_fields[i] = magnetic_vector_in_point(current_coordinates[:, np.newaxis, i], currents[i],
                                                      grid)
        magnetic_fields[i] = mask_area(magnetic_fields[i], grid, [0.00564237, 0.01335], 1)

    def find_dipol_moment(x, fields, slot_cnt, end_points, koordinaten_feld):
        # calculate middle between currents, where dipol should be located.
        dipol_coord = np.mean(end_points[:, 0:2], axis=1)
        # calculate direction of the dipol moment, it is orthogonal to the line between the currents
        vect = end_points[:, 0] - end_points[:, 1]
        dipol_vektor = np.flip(vect, axis=0) * np.array([-1, 1])
        #
        dipol_vektor = dipol_vektor[:, np.newaxis]
        dipol_unit_vektor = - dipol_vektor / np.linalg.norm(dipol_vektor)
        dipol_coord = dipol_coord[:, np.newaxis]
        fields[slot_cnt] = magnetic_dipol_field_in_point(dipol_coord, x[0] * dipol_unit_vektor, koordinaten_feld)
        fields[slot_cnt] = -mask_area(fields[slot_cnt], grid, [0.00564237, 0.01335], 1)
        error_field = np.sum(magnetic_fields, axis=0)
        error = np.nansum(np.linalg.norm(error_field, axis=1))
        print("Dipolmoment:", x,"\tFehler: ", error)
        return error

    res = minimize(find_dipol_moment, -5,  # 1 ist mein anfangswert bei der suche
                   args=(magnetic_fields, 2, current_coordinates, grid))
    x = res.x
    print("Ergebnis: äquivalentes Dipolmoment", x)
    magnetic_field = np.sum(magnetic_fields[0:2], axis=0)
    dipol_field = magnetic_fields[2]
    # overall_field = np.sum(magnetic_fields, axis=0)
    #    magnetic_field = magnetic_fields[2]

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10), dpi=180, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
    ax.scatter(0.00564237, 0.01335, marker="o")
    ax.scatter(a, 0, marker="+")
    ax.scatter(-a / np.sqrt(3), a, marker="+")
    q = ax.quiver(grid[0, :], grid[1, :], magnetic_field[0, :], magnetic_field[1, :], color='b')
    q = ax.quiver(grid[0, :], grid[1, :], dipol_field[0, :], dipol_field[1, :], color = 'k')
    # q = ax.quiver(coordiante_field[0, :], coordiante_field[1, :], overall_field.T[0, :], overall_field.T[1, :],
    #              color='r')
    # print(str(np.nansum(np.linalg.norm(overall_field, axis=1 )) ))
    ax.quiverkey(q, X=0.3, Y=1.1, U=10,
                 label='Quiver key, length = 10', labelpos='E')
    ax.set_aspect('equal', 'box')
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Sounds like the goal here is to find a magnetic dipole field approximating the magnetic field from a given system of stationary electric currents. Instead of a numerical optimization procedure, the right way to do it is to apply multipole expansion to your coil current, that would produce the dipole field as the lowest-order term.

Comment: @MaximUmansky reading about multipole expansion, it sounds as if it was the standard tool for the job. Its new to me, though. Can you please help with the approximation at hand?

Comment: For localized current it will boil down to taking an integral along the path of the current, as explained, e.g., in http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/jk1/lectures/node53.html.
What is the current distribution? Is it a closed loop?

Comment: @MaximUmansky the two line currents (very long, parallel, just in one point) are distance 2a apart and are I1 = -I2. it can be considered a closed loop, but an infietly long one.

Comment: If the currents are long but of finite length L then the dipole moment is $I \cdot 2a \cdot L$. If the length is infinite that is more subtle but probably some approximation can be worked out for the magnetic field using the symmetry of the system.

Comment: I dont see how that helps me with my problem, with very long L. The dipol momentum is certainly not infinit.

Comment: Well, the dipole moment of a current loop is the current times the area of the loop, $A \cdot I$, so for your two infinite wires it is infinite. But the dipole field is defined only for distances much larger than the dipole size, so in the case of infinite size wires it does not apply anyway. But still you can use multipole expansion for the magnetic vector potential in the plane perpendicular to the wires, using cylindrical multipole expansion, and there a dipole term will actually appear, and that will produce the result for the magnetic field at large distances, $R \gg a$.

Comment: @MaximUmansky Thank your for your comment, in the past days I made the same mental journey that you describe - my inital question was wrong and I wanted to compare apples with oranges. I agree with your cylindrical approach, but still dont know how to do the math moving from the dipol point to a dipol line. I have less problems imagining what goes on then writing it down. Can I mail you about this?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/602528/how-to-formulate-the-magnetic-dipol-moment-and-field-in-a-line-geometry-instead

Comment: @MaximUmansky, would you mind expanding your comments into an answer?

Comment: I can do it, sure. However I think there is some confusion on the problem statement, the question posted in Physics Stack Exchange seems to imply that the magnetic dipole moment of the system remains constant as the wires are extended to infinity. That could be achieved only by reducing the current to zero (if the spacing between the wires is given and fixed). Probably what is meant here is the current is finite, and that's a meaningful formulation, and I will post the solution for it asap.

Comment: It is stated https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_dipole#External_magnetic_field_produced_by_a_magnetic_dipole_moment that the magentic moment is kept constant while the source shrinks to a point. Even the fact that a limit is considered is stated explicitly. That is not the case in the lecture you, Maxim, quote in your first comment here. However the decicive "obvious conclusion"  (between equation 676 and 674) comes without motivation.

Comment: @MaximUmansky http://physicsinsights.org/dipole_field_1.html here they derive the field of a magnetic (point) dipol and mention the limit and keeping the product $I \cdot dA$ constant.

Comment: I tried to explain this but maybe not well enough, let me try again. For two infinite parallel wires carrying some finite current $I$ the standard, traditional magnetic dipole moment is infinity, it is not defined. That does not mean the magnetic field is infinite, it just means that the standard magnetic dipole does not apply here. But in my solution I showed that in the 2D plane perpendicular to the wires there is still a multipole expansion that gives a dipole term (for different definition of dipole moment). In 3D the dipole vector potential is $\propto 1/r^{2}$; in 2D it is $\propto 1/r$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We consider two thin infinite straight parallel wires at distance $2                            
a$ apart and carrying equal currents $I$ in opposite directions. We need to find an approximate description of the system in terms of multipole expansion moments.

Let's first make a few preliminary comments. The magnetic field is
described by the magnetic vector potential $\vec{A}$ that is related
to the magnetic field $\vec{B}$ according to $\nabla \times \vec{A} =                           
\vec{B}$, and $\nabla^2 \vec{A} = - \mu_0 \vec{j}$, where $\vec{j}$ is the electric current (using SI units).

Let's use the coordinate $z$ in the direction of the
wires. For an infinite straight wire in the $\hat{e}_z$ direction the
vector potential is also in the $\hat{e}_z$ direction. Due to the symmetry, our problem is 2D and the magnetic field is fully described by a scalar quantity $A_z(x,y)$.

For a single wire located in the 2D plane at $\vec{r}_1 =(x_1,y_1)$ and carrying
current $I_1$ the vector potential is found from $\nabla^2 A_z = -\mu_0 I_1 \delta(\vec{r}-\vec{r}_1)$, where on the right hand side is the delta-function, and the solution is well known to be $A_z = -(\mu_0/2\pi) I_1 \ln(|\vec{r}-\vec{r}_1|)$, where the distance between the observation point and the wire is $|\vec{r}-\vec{r}_1|$.

Further it is convenient to use the polar coordinates $(\rho,\theta)$, thus
a wire is described by the current $I_1$ and its location
($\rho_1,\theta_1$). Then at the observation point $(\rho,\theta)$, using the cosine theorem, we have

$
A_z = -\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi} I_1 \ln(\rho^2 + \rho_1^2 - 2 \rho \rho_1 \cos(\theta-\theta_1))
$

For the far field, assuming $\rho_1 \ll \rho$, we expand the expression as

$
A_z = -\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi} I_1 \left[ \ln(\rho^2) - \ln(1 - \frac{2 \rho_1}{\rho} \cos(\theta-\theta_1)) \right]
\approx
-\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}I_1 \ln(\rho^2) 
-\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi} I_1 \frac{2 \rho_1}{\rho} \cos(\theta-\theta_1)
$

The second term on the right-hand side is the dipole term which can be written as $ -(\mu_0/2\pi) \vec{p}_1 \cdot \vec{r} / r^2$, where the dipole moment is $\vec{p}_1 = I_1 \vec{r}_1$

Now, using superposition, we can immediately generalize for N parallel wires at locations described in the 2D plane by vectors $\vec{r}_k$ and carrying currents $I_k$. The far field at location $\vec{r}$, assuming $|r| \gg |r_k|$, is given by

$
A_z = -\frac{\mu_0}{2\pi} I_{tot} \ln(|r|) 
-\frac{\mu_0}{2\pi} (\vec{p}_{tot} \cdot \vec{r})/r^2
$

where the total current is $I_{tot} = \sum_{k=1}^N I_k$ and the total dipole moment is $\vec{p}_{tot} = \sum_{k=1}^N I_k \vec{r}_k$.

Of course the expansion procedure could be continued further and the exact answer would be an infinite sum of multipole moments; but for the far-away field only the lowest-order terms matter.

Back to the situation with two wires at distance $2a$ apart, the total current is zero so the first (monopole) term vanishes. The total dipole moment is $p_{tot} = 2 a I$ and is in the direction from one wire to the other one, in the plane perpendicular to the wires. The result for $A_z$ is very similar to the electric potential from a regular electric dipole; only the dependence on the distance is different.

Finally, the magnetic field is found from $A_z$ as

$
\vec{B} = \nabla \times \vec{A} = \hat{e}_z \times \nabla A_z
$

Comment: You write that the total current is the sum of all currents. Your vector potential is that of one current. With the two currents in opposit directions, the sum of the currents is zero and hence the dipol moment would be zero, too. Do I understand that correctly?

Comment: No, the monopole moment (the one that gives $\ln(\rho)$ dependence for $A_z$) vanishes. Dipole moment is the second one that gives $1/\rho$ dependence.

Comment: working my way through this. Shouldn't it be $A_z = \frac{\mu I}{4\pi}ln(|r|)$ ?

Comment: In SI units there will be $\mu_0$ there, in CGS there will be speed of light $c$. I'll fix the units asap.